# How to post an uploaded file with http?

Tags: node.js, commonjs, express

How would I do the equivalent of this in an express app? That is,
posting a file to facebook:

```
curl -F 'access_token=xyz' \
    -F 'source=@file.png' \
    -F 'message=Caption for the photo' \
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
```

I'm using the following to upload the file from the example in the repo:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
 req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files){
   if (err) {
     next(err);
   } else {
     console.log('\nuploaded %s to %s'
       ,  files.image.filename
       , files.image.path);
     res.redirect('back');
   }
 });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request)-module, which makes it (almost) too easy:

```
fs.readStream('file.png').pipe(request.post('http://graph.facebook.com/me/photos'))
```

This will create a POST-request to the given URL and stream `file.png` though it. It should be fairly trivial to add the remainder of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTTP request with Node. See the following example in the docs:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#http.request